# Angular 5 how to get the checkboxes values

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a list of checkboxes and I want to get the values of the checkboxes on submitting the form. I see the following issues:

1) All checkboxes are checked when I click on one checkbox.

2) The value of 'purpose' field is in console shows "true" or "false", based on selection.

```
<article class="mb-2 mb-md-4">
        <header class="border-bottom mb-3">
            <h6 class="mb-3"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right mr-2 text-primary"></i>Purpose of Claim</h6>
            <br> The Claim is made against the carrier for:
            <br> (Please tick as appropriate)
        </header>
        <label class="custom-check text-left flex-row">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Loss" value="Loss" name="purpose" [(ngModel)]="purpose" ><span class="checkmark"></span><strong class="font-weight-medium pl-2">Loss</strong>
        </label>
        <label class="custom-check text-left flex-row">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Damage" value="Damage" name="purpose" [(ngModel)]="purpose"><span class="checkmark"></span><strong class="font-weight-medium pl-2">Damage</strong>
        </label>
        <label class="custom-check text-left flex-row">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Incomplete" value="Incomplete" name="purpose" [(ngModel)]="purpose" ><span class="checkmark"></span><strong class="font-weight-medium pl-2">Incomplete
                Item</strong>
        </label>
    </article>
```

Comment: Beacuse you are using same variable for all checkboxes i.e. purpose

Comment: If you don't use the same variable for each, but provide each it's own value, you could read them there from your ViewModel. Otherwise you could go with ViewChildren.. but just read the from the model. Normally you would go with a loop over your model, *ngFor="..."

Comment: @StefanRein can you explain the same as your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In Class:

```
@Component(..)
class FooComponent {
    public items: Array<{purpose: boolean}> = [
        {purpose: true},
        {purpose: false},
        {purpose: true},
        {purpose: false}
    ];
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
    <input type="checkbox" name="name-{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="item.purpose" />
</div>

<pre>
    {{items | json}}
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a form tag in html and in class call : `form.controls['purpose'].value;`